# How to point a subdomain to run applications using virtualenv on ec2 (AWS)

Tags: virtual-machine, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel

I added an ec2 instance (ubuntu server) in aws, installed python3.7, virtualenvs, pointed ec2's elastic ip to a subdomain, entered virtualenvs and made a webapp to run the web application. How do I run runserver.py by accessing sub.dominio.com?

```
/ubuntu/
|── webapp/
|         └── runserver.py (wsgiref)
|──.virtualenvs
```